# Difference between closures and IIFE's in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

According to the Closures concept it will store the variables of the outer lexical environment for future execution of its inner function. For example:

```
function makeYounger(age) {
    function b() { 
        console.log("Original age is :" + age); 
    }
    b();
    return(function() { 
        return age / 2;
    }); 
}
var displayAge = makeYounger(20); 
console.log(displayAge());
```

In the above scenario, `age` is preserved by the Javascript engine to execute the inner function present in the return method.

Here comes the IIFE:

```
 (function(window) { 
     var greeting = "Hello"; 
     var fNameSpace1 = { 
         name : "Appu", 
         callName : function() { 
             console.log(greeting + fNameSpace1.name);
         } 
     };
     window.doer = fNameSpace1; 
 }) (window);

 fNameSpace1.callName(); //To execute the inner function
```

In the above scenario according to the closures concept the variables `greeting` and `fNameSpace1.name` will be stored for future execution of the `callname()` function. Instead we are making use of the `window` object. I am confused why we are going with `window` if we have closures?

Comment: That `fNameSpace1.callName();` at the end will fail. The global is called `doer`, not `fNameSpace1`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If the question is "what's the difference between closures and IIFEs" the answer is "an IIFE is one specific way to create a closure." If the question is "Why are we going with window if we have closures?" the answer is: Because the author wanted to have a global variable.

Comment: My question is what is the exact use of window object in this scenario if the javascript engine already stores fNameSpace1 object.Why are we creating a reference using window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Difference between closures and IIFE's in javascript

An IIFE is just one specific way to A) Create a closure over the context in which it's defined, and B) Create a context in which to create other closures.

> My question is what is the exact use of window object in this scenario if the javascript engine already stores fNameSpace1 object.Why are we creating a reference using window?

So it can be used outside the IIFE, by referring to it via the `doer` global that `window.doer = ...` creates.

There are dozens of different ways to do this. One of them does it by assigning to `window` like that. Another does it by returning the value and using a `var` statement:

```
var doer = (function() {
   // ...
   return fNamespace1;
})();
```

but again, there are dozens of different formations. The author of that particular one just preferred to write to a property on `window` as the way to create the global.

Answer (score 3):

IIFE is useful to avoid global variable pollution when multiple functions are accessing a global variable

Closure functions are helpful when working with a local variable.